# TSQL Two cursors in row by row comparision

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, insert, cursor

I have got two views with data. I compare string from column in first view with every string in column in other view/table. I need to insert result from that comparison into other table.

At the moment i am using two cursors with forward only, going row by row through both views/tables and inserting result. It is so slow for me. Is there any other possibility to do that double loop ( i don't even have Index in second view) than two cursors?

Comment: Views don't *have* data - views are just stored T-SQL statements that get evaluated when you select from a view

Comment: that's true. i missinterprated that

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use cross join

```
INSERT INTO ResultTable
Select a.Column1 - b.Column2 AS Comparison
FROM Table1 AS A
CROSS JOIN Table2 AS B;
```

Cursors are extremely slow

Comment: The problem is one is table, the second one is view. Will that be possible to use cross join here?

Comment: View is just a virtual table.

Comment: is there possibility to add where clause to insert that data only if that Comparison will be for example >0 ?

Comment: @JanWalczak, yes, you can add a where clause.  Do you want to store anything else besides the comparison (like a key value)?